# How to update and delete data in greenplum database using gpkafka?

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, greenplum, debezium

I am trying to replicate data from mysql to greenplum using debezium, kafka and gpkafka. Insert works properly. But  I am not able  to update and delete
data in greenplum. Please let me know whether update and delete are supported by gpkafka utility and what configuration needed in gpkafka yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

I am from Greenplum team that is working on gpKafka.

By now both not supported yet. We are working on update now and it will be available soon. Delete is not in current scope.

Comment: Note Debezium comes with [an SMT](https://debezium.io/docs/configuration/event-flattening/) that lets you rewrite deletes into updates of a "deleted" column. This can be used to remove records marked as deleted on the sink side some sort of batch job for instance.

Comment: Thanks, Gunnar. Soft deleting is indeed a good way to do it. We will consider and should be able to support it.